# Using Python and Pandas dataframe how to groupBy some fields and merge remaining non-grouped fields into list then convert to json

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to ultimately convert this df into json.  I want to merge all rows from the df matching on several columns.  The remaining columns that remain different, I want them in a list contained in a new 'lob' column.  The code below does exactly what I want.  But I'm asking because I feel it's really ugly and this is a downsized example.  I have many more columns that will and won't match so this will get ugly quickly.

New to Python and Pandas so explanations will be very helpful.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
        "policyNumber":        ["1234", "2uss", "1234", "4hin", "5out", "6raz"],
        "policyEffectiveDate": ["5678", "2uss", "5678", "4hin", "5out", "6raz"],
        "policyStatus":        ["abcd", "2uss", "abcd", "4hin", "5out", "6raz"],
        "lob":                 ["1raz", "2uss", "3ndi", "4hin", "5out", "6raz"],
        "lobStatus":           ["1raz", "2uss", "3ndi", "4hin", "5out", "6raz"],
        "lobDate":             ["1raz", "2uss", "3ndi", "4hin", "5out", "6raz"]
     }

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

agg = lambda x: [{'lob':k, 'lobStatus':v, 'lobDate':w} for k, v, w in zip(x['lob'], x['lobStatus'], x['lobDate'])]

policyLevelFields = ['policyNumber', 'policyEffectiveDate', 'policyStatus']

grouped = df.groupby(policyLevelFields)
groupedDf = grouped.apply(agg).reset_index(name='lob')
result = groupedDf.to_json(orient="records")
```

output:

```
[
   {
      "policyNumber":"1234",
      "policyEffectiveDate":"5678",
      "policyStatus":"abcd",
      "lob":[
         {
            "lob":"1raz",
            "lobStatus":"1raz",
            "lobDate":"1raz"
         },
         {
            "lob":"3ndi",
            "lobStatus":"3ndi",
            "lobDate":"3ndi"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "policyNumber":"2uss",
      "policyEffectiveDate":"2uss",
      "policyStatus":"2uss",
      "lob":[
         {
            "lob":"2uss",
            "lobStatus":"2uss",
            "lobDate":"2uss"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "policyNumber":"4hin",
      "policyEffectiveDate":"4hin",
      "policyStatus":"4hin",
      "lob":[
         {
            "lob":"4hin",
            "lobStatus":"4hin",
            "lobDate":"4hin"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "policyNumber":"5out",
      "policyEffectiveDate":"5out",
      "policyStatus":"5out",
      "lob":[
         {
            "lob":"5out",
            "lobStatus":"5out",
            "lobDate":"5out"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "policyNumber":"6raz",
      "policyEffectiveDate":"6raz",
      "policyStatus":"6raz",
      "lob":[
         {
            "lob":"6raz",
            "lobStatus":"6raz",
            "lobDate":"6raz"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `to_dict` to convert the column to dict records first, then assign to new column.

```
dfn = df[['policyNumber', 'policyEffectiveDate', 'policyStatus',]].copy()
dfn['lob'] = df[['lob', 'lobStatus', 'lobDate']].to_dict(orient="records")
dfn = dfn.groupby(['policyNumber', 'policyEffectiveDate', 'policyStatus'], as_index=False)['lob'].agg(list)
print(dfn.to_json(orient="records", indent=4))
```

---

```
[
    {
        "policyNumber":"1234",
        "policyEffectiveDate":"5678",
        "policyStatus":"abcd",
        "lob":[
            {
                "lob":"1raz",
                "lobStatus":"1raz",
                "lobDate":"1raz"
            },
            {
                "lob":"3ndi",
                "lobStatus":"3ndi",
                "lobDate":"3ndi"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "policyNumber":"2uss",
        "policyEffectiveDate":"2uss",
        "policyStatus":"2uss",
        "lob":[
            {
                "lob":"2uss",
                "lobStatus":"2uss",
                "lobDate":"2uss"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "policyNumber":"4hin",
        "policyEffectiveDate":"4hin",
        "policyStatus":"4hin",
        "lob":[
            {
                "lob":"4hin",
                "lobStatus":"4hin",
                "lobDate":"4hin"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "policyNumber":"5out",
        "policyEffectiveDate":"5out",
        "policyStatus":"5out",
        "lob":[
            {
                "lob":"5out",
                "lobStatus":"5out",
                "lobDate":"5out"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "policyNumber":"6raz",
        "policyEffectiveDate":"6raz",
        "policyStatus":"6raz",
        "lob":[
            {
                "lob":"6raz",
                "lobStatus":"6raz",
                "lobDate":"6raz"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: This is close but the object with policyNumber 1234 should be merged as seen in my output above.  I edited my question to make the policyStatus match for these two, setting it to 'abcd' in both cases.  They didn't match, but should have, in the original question. My mistake.

Comment: then use `groupby` and apply `agg(list)`. update the answer.